# Is it possible to use a static class to group extension methods?

Tags: c#

Adding extension methods is simple via:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static string MyMethodOne(this string aSource)
    {
        return aSource += "My Method One";
    }

    public static string MyMethodTwo(this string aSource)
    {
        return aSource += "My Method Two";
    }
}
```

and callable as:

```
"some string".MyMethodOne();
"some string".MyMethodTwo();
```

However I have a large number of method and want to "group them" using a static class container:

```
public static class MyStringExtensionsGroup
{
    public static string MethodOne(string aSource)
    {
        return aSource += "My Method One";
    }

    public static string MethodTwo(string aSource)
    {
        return aSource += "My Method Two";
    }
}
```

So assuming I somehow expose `My : MyStringExtensionsGroup` as a string extension I could end up calling things with the following convention (note period after `My`):

```
"some string".My.MethodOne();
"some string".My.MethodTwo();
```

and say I had another grouping called '''MyOtherGroup''' I could then do:

```
"some string".MyOtherGroup.MethodOne();
"some string".MyOtherGroup.MethodTwo();
```

Is any "grouping" of extension methods possible with what C# currently provides?

Comment: It isn't possible in a simple way, and without creating extra intermediate (instances of) objects.

Comment: I assume you are purposely not using `this` with `MethodOne`?

Comment: @mjwills MethodOne() is not an extension method ;-)

Comment: Cool - just clarifying that you understood that, since it seemed odd that you expected `"some string".MyOtherGroup.MethodOne();` to _ever_ work in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extensions methods* can't be *nested*, however with a lot of mindless fiddling you could create your own *fluent syntax*.

**Extensions**

```
public static class MyStringExtensionsGroup
{
   public static string MethodOne(this Group1 group) => group.Source + "My Method One";
   public static string MethodTwo(this Group2 group) => group.Source + "My Method Two";
   public static Group1 Group1(this string source) => new Group1(source);
   public static Group2 Group2(this string source) => new Group2(source);
}
```

**Groups**

```
public class Group1
{
   public string Source { get; }
   public Group1(string source) => Source = source;
}

public class Group2
{
   public string Source { get; }
   public Group2(string source) => Source = source;
}
```

Or you could just stuff your methods in the class, which is neater

```
public class Group1
{
   public string Source { get; }
   public Group1(string source) => Source = source;
   public string MethodOne() => Source + "My Method One";
   public string MethodTwo() => Source + "My Method Two";
}

public class Group2
{
   public string Source { get; }
   public Group2(string source) => Source = source;
   public string MethodOne() => Source + "My Method One";
   public string MethodTwo() => Source + "My Method Two";
}
```

Either way the usage is the same

**Usage**

```
var someString = "asd";
Console.WriteLine(someString.Group1().MethodOne());
Console.WriteLine(someString.Group2().MethodTwo());
```

***Note*** : There are other ways and structures that can do this, however this will get you started if you want to go down this rabbit hole

**In summary, I wouldn't do this at all :)**

Comment: Thank you for going to the effort of writing it up! You're a better [human] than I am.

Comment: @John completely the case that i am trying to dodge my own work :)

Comment: This is just evil.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes it would be failing my code review with a note saying dont do this again :P

Comment: So how do you handle say 30 extension methods off a class that are then interspersed with either M$'s or someone elses? Do you just leave the "public" interface polluted? How do you prevent naming collisions? What is the "better" way to do this?

Comment: @TheEdge not much you can do about naming collisions, apart from using the right using directive or calling the fully qualified static method. However what you are running into is one of the bad parts of extensions and why they are a bit of a smell. there is no language feature orientated way around this

Comment: Is it less of a smell to say have a class with a constructor taking the string and said class exposes methods. So in essence var myExtensions = new MyStringExtentions(someString); var fooSomeString = myExtensions.MethodOne();?

Comment: @TheEdge you could create a instance class or even a pure static class for that reason which takes no constructor and then you can group all your utility methods together (you lose the fluent feel of extensions though). or if this business logic, sometimes its best that it resides in services that are injectable, what you do depends on what you need. Extension methods aren't bad, but i would err against create one for everything. If you want to debate the pros and cons of your situation, you might post to SoftwareEngineering site, those kids dont mind talking about good design patterns